# Producing a value based off a coordinate system

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, n-queens

I'm stuck on a problem where we have to

```
build_board(coords,size):

Given a list of coordinates for the locations of 
int size, build a board (a list of lists of Booleans) of that size, and mark cells with a queen
True.
```

Examples:

```
 build_board([(0,0)],1) → [[True]]

 build_board([(0,0)],2) → [[True,   False], [False, False]]

 build_board([(0,0),(1,1)],2) → [[True, False], [False, True]]
```

The context is that we made a function to make the board as such

```
def build_empty_board(size):
    size=int(size)
    ans = [ [False for x in range(size)] for x in range(size) ]
    return ans
```

However I don't know how to code a loop that checks each board made and produce values off a coordinate system. Could anyone guide me on how to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this approach:

```
def build_board(coords, size):
    # if any(i < 0 for coord in coords for i in coord):
    #     return
    board = [[False] * size for _ in range(size)]
    for (row, col) in coords:
        if row < 0 or col < 0:
            return
        board[row][col] = True
    return board

print(build_board([(0,0)],1)) #[[True]]
print(build_board([(0,0)],2)) #[[True,   False], [False, False]]
print(build_board([(0,0),(1,1)],2)) #[[True, False], [False, True]]
print(build_board([(0,0),(-1,3)],2)) #None
```

Comment: This seems to work but I keep running into an error on this line apparently. board[row][col] = True. The error is an index error: list index out of range. Any fix?

Comment: Can you tell me the parameters you're calling it with?

Comment: oh wait, I think it's because of this:build_board([(0,0),(-1,3)],2) → None  #invalid coordinate. Any negative coordinate is supposed to produce None. I think this may be the reason? Could you incoporate this into your code as well? Sorry :3

Comment: @Jessica see my updated answer. Also what about negative sizes? Or does that case not matter?

Comment: Yep does not matter for negative sizes, thank you! One last question, if any(i < 0 for coord in coords for i in coord): what is the second part testing for and how come this code doesn't work if I delete the "any"? We have not learned the function "any" so we may not be able to use it